# Python check string pattern follows xxxx-yyyy-zzzz

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a check for strings that allows a pattern "xxxx-yyyy-zzzz". The string needs to have three blocks seperated by "-". Each block can contain "a-z", "A-Z", "_" (underscore) and "." (dot).

This is what I got to now:

```
file_name: str = "actors-zero-This_Is_Fine.exe.yml"
ab = re.compile("^([A-Z][0-9])-([A-Z][0-9])-([A-Z][0-9])+$")
if ab.match(file_name):
    pass
else:
    print(f"WARNING wrong syntax in {file_name}")
    sys.exit()
```

Output is:

> WARNING wrong name in actors-zero-This_Is_Fine.exe.yml

Comment: And what is the problem with what you've done?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info and http://regex101.com…

Comment: "This is what I got to now:" Okay, so **what happens** when you try that code? **How is that different** from what you expect to happen? When asking a question, please **ask** a question, don't just explain a code requirement and show an attempt.

Comment: BTW, your description doesn't specify that decimal digits are permitted, but your code seems to allow them.

Comment: Maybe `[A-Z0-9_.]+`?

Comment: practically, `^` and `$` describe the start and end of a string respectively - what happens if you remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want 3 groups of alphanumerical characters (plus .) separated by dashes:
Regex for this would be `^([\w.]+)-([\w.]+)-([\w.]+)$`

`^` matches the start of a string
Then we have 3 repeating groups:
`([\w.]+)` will match letters, numbers, underscores (`\w`) and dots (`.`) at least one time (`+`)
We make 3 of these, then separate each with a dash.

We finish off the regex with a `$` to match the end of the string, making sure you're matching the whole thing.

Comment: This worked: ^([\w.]+)-([\w.]+)-([\w.]+)$
This doesnt: ^([A-z_.]+)-([A-z_.]+)-([A-z_.]+)$

Comment: `[A-z]` matches more than only letters, have a look at an ASCII table.

Comment: @Europa, do you need numbers too? If so, `\w` would work.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question?
This looks alright so far. Your `file name` returns the warning because you have not specified the underscores in the third "block".

Instead of `([A-Z][0-9])`. you could use character classes:

[image]

Like so: `^([\w.]+)-([\w.]+)-([\w.]+)$`

Generally, I found the chapter in Automate The Boring Stuff on regex Pattern matching very concise and helpful:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter7/
You will find the above table in this chapter also.